# random variable convergence in $L^1$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration and $Z$ an integrable random variable. Put $Z_t = E(Z|\mathcal{F_t)}$. Show that $Z_t \to Z_{\infty}=E(Z|\mathcal{F_\infty})$ in $L^1$ where $\mathcal{F_\infty}=\sigma (\cup_{t\ge 0}\mathcal{F_t})$. Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: What do you know about the convergence of martingales? (Hint: $Z_t$ is a martingale which is uniformly integrable.)

Comment: Not too much but i think i can figure it out now. How did you see its uniformly integrable? @saz

Comment: For any integrable random variable $Z$ the family $$\{\mathbb{E}(Z \mid \mathcal{F}); \mathcal{F} \, \, \text{(sub-)$\sigma$-algebra}\}$$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: ok, thank you very much @saz